# GeoFirestore GeoFire dependency not allowing me to update Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, geofire, geofirestore

I am using Firebase and GeoFirestore. I want to update my Firebase pod, so I updated the GeoFirestore podspec dependency to 'Firebase', '~> 6.1.0'. However, Geofirestore has a Geofire dependancy which has a Firebase/Database (~>5.0) dependency. How can I get the latest Firebase with the 5.0 Geofire dependency?

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    Geofirestore (from `https://collinesmon@github.com/CollinEsmon/GeoFirestore-iOS.git`) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (~> 5.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Database (~> 5.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: Running `pod update` fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding GeoFirestore and Geofire to my app manually instead of using cocoapods. That seemed to be the only solution for now.

Comment: how did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my pod:

`pod 'Geofirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS.git'`

I found it from [here](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS/issues/19).